# Empty NSArray's are equal?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I was wondering, why this code:

```
NSArray *emptyArr = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *emptyArrA = [NSArray arrayWithArray:emptyArr];
NSArray *emptyArrB = [NSArray arrayWithArray:emptyArr];

NSLog(@"emptyArrA == emptyArrB => %d", (emptyArrA == emptyArrB));
NSLog(@"emptyArr == emptyArrB => %d", (emptyArr == emptyArrB));
NSLog(@"emptyArrA == emptyArr => %d", (emptyArrA == emptyArr));
```

output the following:

```
emptyArrA == emptyArrB => 1
emptyArr == emptyArrB => 1
emptyArrA == emptyArr => 1
```

that is, the objects seem to be indentical? Hmm, I thought, this must be a iOS (or CoreFoundation?) optimization on the special case of the immutable, empty NSArray, which then always resolves to the same object instance.

But...this code:

```
NSLog(@"emptyArr => %p", &emptyArr);
NSLog(@"emptyArrA => %p", &emptyArrA);
NSLog(@"emptyArrB => %p", &emptyArrB);
```

outputs (on my machine):

```
emptyArr => 0xbfffdd64
emptyArrA => 0xbfffdd60
emptyArrB => 0xbfffdd5c
```

which to me indicates 3 *different* instances.

How come the "==" operator then tell me they are identical objects?

Is it clever compiler optimzations?

**--UPDATE--**

Given the below answers, I'm still a bit confused :-). I'll expand a bit on my question here..

The answers tell me, that "&arrayObject" takes the address of the *variable*, as opposed to the object, and I guess this code tells me that to be true:

```
NSLog(@"emptyArr => %p", &*emptyArr);
NSLog(@"emptyArrA => %p", &*emptyArrA);
NSLog(@"emptyArrB => %p", &*emptyArrB);
```

because it outputs:

```
emptyArr => 0x6829fd0
emptyArrA => 0x6829fd0
emptyArrB => 0x6829fd0
```

which indicates the same object. But this indicates (to me at least), that there is some kind  "magic" in the "==" operator for NSObject instances, that actually make it compare pointers to the objects behind the variable instead of pointers to the variabel. Is that correct?

Because, if I do the same thing with an "int*", I *must* dereference it to get equality. Like this:

```
int *i1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
*i1 = 42;
int *i2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
*i2 = 42;

NSLog(@"i1 == i2 => %d", (i1 == i2));
NSLog(@"*i1 == *i2 => %d", (*i1 == *i2));
```

which gives me:

```
i1 == i2 => 0
*i1 == *i2 => 1
```

which is also what I would expect from my (somewhat dated) C experiences :-)

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second test takes the address of the *variables*, and correctly indicates that there are *three different variables*. All three variables point to the same empty array instance — as an optimization, NSArray always returns the same empty array, and `arrayWithArray:` on NSArrays just retains the argument, since it is immutable and thus they're indistinguishable anyway. If you want to see that, take out the `&` operator in all of your log statements. If you had tested `&emptyArrA == &emptyArrB`, you would have seen that false too.

---

To answer your new question: No, there's no magic. It's just normal pointer equality. When you write `somePointer == someOtherPointer`, it always tells you whether they point to the same address, regardless of type — `int`, `BOOL`, `NSMutableAttributedString*`, any type. It compares the addresses *stored in* the pointers. It will never compare magically pointers to the pointers.

I think what you're missing is that objects are always referenced by pointers — they are never direct values like ints. To test objects for value equality rather than pointer equality, you need a method like `isEqual:`.

Comment: so by that logic, if I were to use `NSMutableArray` the first test would indicate different?

Comment: +1 Interesting question, but I think Chuck nailed it.  The variables are indeed distinct, but not the object they point to.  The comparisons are comparing the object pointer which all match.  If you were to compare the address of the variables themselves, sure they'd be different (that's what is shown on the NSLogs), but that would be a little pointless as well.

Comment: @Srikar: Yes, if you used NSMutableArrays instead of plain NSArrays, they would all be distinct objects.

Comment: @chuck based on your answer (thank you) I expanded a bit on my question, as I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an optimization: NSArrays are immutable so all empty NSArrays are equivalent and the compiler is deciding not to create new instances for emptyArrA and emptyArrB.

Note that the three NSArray pointers **all point to the same instance** but you are displaying the variable address **not** the address of the object pointed to. This is what is confusing you.

Comment: The == operator should compare the pointers, NOT the objects pointed at by the pointer.  To compare the objects you would need to use some kind of compare method.  Common is string compares with either `[@"hello" isEqualToString:@"world"]` or `[@"hello" compare:@"world"]`

Comment: The == operator compares the **value** of two variables - in the case of pointer variables it compares whether the variables point to the same memory address. In this case they do  - and you can verify it in the debugger. All three NSArray pointers are pointing to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

emptyArr, emptyArrA, and emptyArrB are three different variables, so taking the address of them will always be different. It appears that all three of these variables contain references to the same empty array object, as you have validated in your equality check